# Exported functions form C++ dll in vb.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I'm working with a unmanaged dll written in C++ of a supplier and I want to use the exported functions of the dll in VB.NET to get some measurements of the suppliers device. This is new for me. I get an error when I declare: 
Public m_FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO As New FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO()

The error is: Delegate function requires an "AddressOf" expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.Below you find the code that I use at this moment.

```
Public Delegate Function CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO(ByVal nAngleMilliDegrees As Integer, ByVal dTimeStamp As Date, ByVal nStationNr As Integer, ByVal i64UserData As Long) As Boolean
Public Delegate Function FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO(ByVal fnc As CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO) As Boolean

 Private m_FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO As New FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO()
 Private Function L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO(ByVal fcn As CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO) As Integer
   If m_FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO Then
      Return m_FNC_L3D_SET_CB_ON_NEW_ANGLE_SERVO(fcn)
   Else
       Return 0
   End If
 End Function
```

Comment: If you want to keep your sanity, write an interop assembly in [C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx).

Comment: :-) I'm using a dll written in C++ from the customer. I'm not familiar with C++ programming. I want to program in vb.net.

Comment: You can use a C++/CLI assembly from VB.NET like any other managed assembly. C++/CLI just makes the translation between managed and unmanaged code so much easier.